# XSLTProcessor.transformToDocument returns null in Chrome/Webkit

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xslt, webkit

I want to process web pages with XSLTProcessor on Chrome or Safari mobile browsers (Webkit).

My tests worked well in Firefox but not in Chrome/Safari browsers. The function transformToDocument returns null, except with very simple documents.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello&nbsp;world</p>
<div>transformToDocument:</div>
<script>
  var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer ();
  var domParser = new DOMParser ();
  var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor ();
  var xslString = '<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
      '<xsl:output method="html"/>' +
      '<xsl:template match="//p"><p><i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i></p></xsl:template>' +
      '<xsl:template match="text()"/>' +
      '</xsl:transform>';
  var xsl = domParser.parseFromString (xslString, 'text/xml');
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet (xsl);
  var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument (document);
  console.log (result); // null with Chrome
  console.log (xmlSerializer.serializeToString (result));
  document.writeln (xmlSerializer.serializeToString (result));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Curiously if I remove the `meta` tag and the `nbsp` entity, the sample works.

Can you please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you getting the error only when running the method on an HTML DOM document? Or also if you use XSLT on an XML DOM document (e.g. created with DOMParser or loaded with XMLHttpRequest)?

Comment: I want to use it for HTML documents. (I tested successfully on some XML docs but this is not my use case.) I have no control on the HTML docs.

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to solve that by changes in your Javascript code, I guess that is an architectural problem in Chrome, not sure how the feed a HTML DOM document to their XSLT processor. In general there is a low compatibility between Mozilla browsers and other browsers when it comes to using XSLTProcessor, that API was never standardised and specified in depth as far as I know and while Chrome and Edge on the surface provide the same methods as Mozilla browsers their internal architectures differ.

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for a compatibility with Mozilla, I'm just trying to make it work on Webkit browsers, more precisely mobile Chrome and Safari. If you tell me that it won't work, this is really bad news, because it would be a basic need for my project...

Comment: Well, you seem to have found cases where it doesn't work. I am afraid I don't know whether Chrome developers would regard any such cases as bugs they would intend to fix to make them work in the future or whether they consider XSLT on HTML DOM as something the APIs allow but which is not a supported or intended use case of the API implementation.

Comment: In terms of my knowlege of XSLT and the XSLTProcessor API the only change in your sample, given that you use `transformToDocument`, to create a complete document, I would try is to ensure the XSLT creates a complete HTML document structure and not only some `p` elements. On the other hand, if the `meta` or the entity reference cause the problems, I don't think that change can fix those problems. They appear to be caused by some problems to feed HTML to the XSLTProcessor.

Comment: Your comments gave me the inspiration to find a solution. As XSLTProcessor works with XML not HTML, the trick is to convert HTML to XML, using XMLSerializer then DOMParser. This may not be super efficient but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply to my own question:

- Convert the input HTML to XML with XMLSerializer then DOMParser.
- Replace nbsp entities to work around a bug (?) in Safari.

  var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument (domParser.parseFromString (xmlSerializer.serializeToString (document).replace ('&nbsp;', '&#160;'), 'text/xml'));